# Finding whether a latlng exists in the given a region using golang/geo/s2

Tags: go, geolocation

I am trying to find if a given LatLng exists in a Desired area.
I am using `github.com/golang/geo/s2`.

```
rect := s2.RectFromLatLng(s2.LatLng{0.0, 0.0})
rect = rect.AddPoint(s2.LatLng{2.0, 2.0})
isThere := rect.ContainsLatLng(s2.LatLng{1.0, 1.0})
fmt.Printf("%+v", rect.Hi())
fmt.Printf("%+v", rect.Lo())
println(isThere)
```

I'm expecting it to return `true` but it gives false. Also, `rect.Hi()` and `rect.Lo()` are same.

Could someone help me understand it better, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**s2.LatLng** creates a point based on radian and not in degree,
you should try using **s2.LatLngFromDegrees()** API.